# What are the products formed by the thermal decomposition of DMPA photoinitiator?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am using DMPA as a photoinitiator for my experiments to polymerise acryamides  and actylates. I need to know if the DMPA used for the purpose forms any decomposition products if heated at high temperature. I tried to search the literature but could not find any useful information. If anyone knows and could help me I would really appreciate that!

Comment: What is "high temperatures"? Heat the pure DMPA, the mixture with monomer, the polymer? What do you expect? What are you afraid of?